# Transforming the parametric equations of a curve into an implicit equation in Cartesian coordinates

Tags: equation-solving, parametric-functions, coordinate-transformation

I have a parametric curve defined by

```
x = 2 Sin[t] + Sin[3 t]   
y = 2 Cos[t] - Cos[3 t]
```

How can I eliminate `t` so get a single implicit equation in `x` and `y`?

Comment: Non-implicit solution: `Solve[{x == 2 Sin[t] + Sin[3 t], y == 2 Cos[t] - Cos[3 t]}, {t, y}]`.

Comment: have you tried the code? When you solve for y,t you automatically eliminate t... Hence the equation is expressed in terms of x and y. Next time try running the code...

Comment: @T.F: Sorry. `y=f(x)` is not what I need. I need `f(x, x^2, x^3, ..., y, y^2, y^3,...)=0`. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should first rationalize the trig functions and the use `Eliminate`:

```
Clear[x, y]

Eliminate[
 TrigExpand[{x == 2 Sin[t] + Sin[3 t], y == 2 Cos[t] - Cos[3 t]} /. 
   t -> 2 ArcTan[u]], u]

(*
==> x^6 + x^4 (17 + 3 y^2) + x^2 (63 - 94 y^2 + 3 y^4) == 
 81 - 63 y^2 - 17 y^4 - y^6
*)
```

The replacement rule introduces the rationalization with variable `u`.